# MongoDB query on Index

Tags: mongodb

Each element in collection has following format:

```
{
   "Name": "Some Name",
   "Description": "Some description",
   "Tags": ["java", "code", "some tag"]
}
```

I have created index on field "Tags" as follows:

```
db.Establishments.ensureIndex({ Tags: 1 });
```

Now I want to make query to find out all the tags that begins with "ja" for example (for auto-complete suggestion).

Instead of querying collection is there a way to query index directly, or efficient query which involves operation on index only?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you actually want to query the tag attribute and return distinct values for your autocompletion feature, right?

This is quite easy using the distinct method:

```
db.Establishments.distinct( 'Tags' )
```

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/ for more info on distinct queries

As to your question about index queries: you can't ask an index directly - the index serves query optimization as such. Using distinct on an indexed attribute will be quick.

To query the distinct method, execute:

```
db.Establishments.distinct( 'Tags', { 'Tags': /^ja/ } )
```

Comment: Yes I want distinct Tags but starting with particular prefix.

Comment: Well that's easy: db.Establishments.distinct( 'Tags' { Tags: { /.*ja.*/ } } ) - that would be the mongo equivalent of SQL's like *ja* - the query param takes a regular expression

Comment: db.Establishments.distinct( 'Tags', { Tags : { $regex : /^foo/ }})  didn't work.

Suppose there are two data as following.
 
 {
  Tags:  [ "food","drinks","burger" ]
  //...
 }
 
 {
  Tags: [ "drive", "motor", "ride" ]
  //...
 }
 
Above query returns.
[ "food", "drinks", "burger" ]

But expected is
["food"]

Comment: The query is wrong, it has to be this: db.Establishment.distinct('Tags', {'Tags' : /^foo/ }); no $regex, no quotes after the secound 'Tags' param

Comment: Could you use it? If yes, please accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: Both expression give same output. Result for the query db.Establishments.distinct( 'Tags', { 'Tags': /^foo/ } )  is as follows {
    "0" : " dinner",
    "1" : " starters",
    "2" : "food",
    "3" : "coffee",
    "4" : "hang out",
    "5" : "snacks",
    "6" : "tea",
    "7" : "veg"
}

Comment: Is Tags an object? Can you please paste it's structure? You'll need a dot notation query for that.

Comment: Tags is array of string. Following is the structure of single element in Establishments collection 
{
   "Name": "Some Name",
   "Description": "Some description",
   "Tags": ["java", "code", "some tag"]
}